# ZFS writes a lot to my disk

Tags: zfs

I'm trying to figure out why my ZFS disks are written to so much.

Using `nmon` and `zfs iostat`, I can see heavy writing activity (around 10M), but with `iotop` I see only a few bytes written. On this machine the overall activity is quite small. I'm worried my disks will wear off prematurely.

How can I investigate this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of its on-disk format (specifically the Merkle tree of checksums), ZFS is relatively write-happy. Regular 10 MB writes with very limited data updates seems a little write-heavy, but not truly extraordinarily so.

The one thing I can think of that would be exacerbating this is if you have atime updates turned on. Check the output of `zfs get atime pool/dataset`, and adjust if you are unhappy.

However, as to your larger question:

> I'm worried my disks will wear off prematurely.

this is **highly unlikely to be a problem.**

Rotational, magnetic HDDs (traditional "hard disks") don't see any significantly increased wear merely because they are asked to write data: they do not suffer from anything like SSDs' limited write counts per cell. So HDDs don't have this problem at all. (For HDDs, power-on hours and power cycle counts are more likely to be problematic.)

SSDs do *in theory* "wear out" based on write activity, but modern SSDs [are not really less reliable than rotational HDDs](https://serverfault.com/a/507536/58408) in practice, even in heavy use.

As an anecdotal example, I have a SSD-backed ZFS pool on my system, with two Intel 535 SSDs in a mirror configuration that have been in service for about 4,000 power-on hours (half a year) according to SMART data and which sees relatively high workstation-type activity (both read and write). The "media wearout indicator" SMART attribute on both of those indicates that they have an estimated 98% life remaining. Based on that, they would hold up to a good 20-25 years of my use; far longer than I would want to trust *any* storage media for anything I want to keep. Compare this to the fact that they are warrantied by Intel for a comparatively measly five years.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer :) my dataset is based on two mirrored HDD ; according to smart power_on_hours is 14100, and atime is off.

Comment: @greg That's not your dataset, it's your vdev; the only way you can have mirrored *datasets* is by increasing the `copies` property on the dataset (filesystem or zvol). (Vdev mirroring is something else.) As I said in my answer, HDDs don't wear out based on write activity, so no need to worry about write activity specifically in that regard. Just make sure you [have good backups](http://serverfault.com/q/2888/58408) and plan to replace your HDDs once every few years. If this answer helped solve your problem, please indicate so by upvoting; if it answered your question, by accepting. Thank you.